# Cambiar contenido de una tabla/celda cuando sea NULL, ESPACIO, SIN ESPACIO

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Estoy tratando de reemplazar los datos de una tabla, les explico:
Tengo mi array

`$prueba = array("Julio", "Anzures", "Calle Oriente 237", "$5000","", null," ");`
Lo que busco al momento de pintarlos en una tabla no hay mas problema

```
<table id="datos" class="table table-bordered">
<thead>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th>Apellido</th>
  <th>Direccion</th>
  <th>Pago</th>
  <th>aqui sin espacio</th>
  <th>aqui nulo</th>
  <th>aqui espacio</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <?php foreach ($prueba as $key => $value): ?>
      <td><?= $value?></td>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

ahora, lo que se busca hacer es:

- Cada que aparezca un elemento **SIN ESPACIO, ESPACIO, NULO** se coloque en ese nodo el texto **VACIO**
  Hasta el momento he podido realizar el bucle para recorrer cada celda de la tabla pero no logro identificar los valores especificados.

```js
var table = document.getElementById('datos');
  for (var r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
    for (var c = 0, m = table.rows[r].cells.length; c < m; c++) {
      alert(table.rows[r].cells[c].innerText)        
     }
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>titulo</title> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <table id="datos" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Apellido</th>
      <th>Direccion</th>
      <th>Pago</th>
      <th>aqui sin espacio</th>
      <th>aqui nulo</th>
      <th>aqui espacio</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>Julio</td>
       <td>Anzures</td>
       <td>Calle Oriente 237</td>
       <td>$5000</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero puedan echarme una mano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta haciendo un foreach de todas las celdas de la pagina, con el innerHTML de cada celda si la longitud es 0

```
<table id="datos" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>Direccion</th>
        <th>Pago</th>
        <th>aqui sin espacio</th>
        <th>aqui nulo</th>
        <th>aqui espacio</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($prueba as $key => $value): ?>
            <td><?= $value ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
const celdas = document.querySelectorAll('tbody td')
celdas.forEach(celda => {
  let value = celda.innerHTML.trim()
  if((value || '').length === 0) celda.innerHTML = 'VACIO'
})
```

Comment: Hola, si lo pensé y funciona pero tengo cerca de 300 tablas en mi proyecto y no creo que pueda poner en todos la validación por eso busco hacerlo con Js

Comment: Modifique mi respuesta, espero te ayude

Comment: gracias! lo resolvi de diferente manera!

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que los datos del array provienen de una consulta de una tabla en una base de datos, lo más eficiente sería que esa consulta arrojara de una vez los datos necesarios:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN nombres IS NULL THEN 'VACÍO'
        WHEN nombres = '' THEN 'VACÍO'
        ELSE (SELECT nombres)
    END nombres,
    CASE 
        WHEN apellidos IS NULL THEN 'VACÍO'
        WHEN apellidos = '' THEN 'VACÍO'
        ELSE (SELECT apellidos)
    END apellidos,
    CASE 
        WHEN direccion IS NULL THEN 'VACÍO'
        WHEN direccion = '' THEN 'VACÍO'
        ELSE (SELECT direccion)
    END direccion,
    CASE 
        WHEN pago IS NULL THEN 'VACÍO'
        WHEN pago = '' THEN 'VACÍO'
        ELSE (SELECT pago)
    END pago,
    CASE 
        WHEN posible_campo_sin_espacio IS NULL THEN 'VACÍO'
        WHEN posible_campo_sin_espacio = '' THEN 'VACÍO'
        ELSE (SELECT posible_campo_sin_espacio)
    END posible_campo_sin_espacio,
    CASE 
        WHEN posible_campo_nulo IS NULL THEN 'VACÍO'
        WHEN posible_campo_nulo = '' THEN 'VACÍO'
        ELSE (SELECT posible_campo_nulo)
    END posible_campo_nulo,
    CASE 
        WHEN posible_campo_vacio IS NULL THEN 'VACÍO'
        WHEN posible_campo_vacio = '' THEN 'VACÍO'
        ELSE (SELECT posible_campo_vacio)
    END posible_campo_vacio
FROM tabla
```

Comment: Muchas gracias pero como comenté arriba mi proyecto contiene cerca de 300 tablas.

Comment: ¿300 tablas html cuyos datos a mostrar provienen de la ejecución de un query en base de datos? o ¿300 tablas html cuyos datos a mostrar provienen de la ejecución de 300 querys en base de datos?. Si es en el caso de la segunda pregunta, entonces ciertamente lo ideal sería valerse de JavaScript, en ese caso @VictorAlvarez ofrece una solución.